# Testing Solidity Code with JavaScript - Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')"

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, uniswap

The following YouTube tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6QVsGeFprU\](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6QVsGeFprU%5C)
references the code for SwapExamples.sol (code to transact on Uniswap), which can be found at the following repo:
https://github.com/stakewithus/defi-by-example/blob/main/uni-v3/contracts/SwapExamples.sol

It compiles in Solidity, but when I run the following test below (simplified version of the code from this link and highlighted on the tutorial)
https://github.com/stakewithus/defi-by-example/blob/main/uni-v3/test/swap.test.js
I get the following errors, that the JS test seems to be having trouble reading the 'address' in the swapExactInputSingle and swapExactOutputSingle portions of SwapExamples.sol:

1. SwapExamples 
   swapExactInputSingle: 
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address') 
   at Context. (test/swap.test.js:31:62) 
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 
   at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3) 
   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) 
   at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
2. SwapExamples 
   swapExactOutputSingle: 
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address') 
   at Context. (test/swap.test.js:45:62) 
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 
   at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3) 
   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) 
   at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

The following is the JavaScript test code:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
const WETH9 = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

describe("SwapExamples", function () {
    let swapExamples;
    let accounts;
    let weth;
    let dai;

    before(async () => {
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

        weth = await ethers.getContractAt("IWETH", WETH9);
        dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);

        const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapExamples");
        const swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy();
        await swapExamples.deployed();
    })

    it("swapExactInputSingle", async function () {
        const amountIn = 10n ** 18n;

        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).deposit({ value: amountIn });
        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn);

        await swapExamples.swapExactInputSingle(amountIn);

        console.log("DAI balance", await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address));
    });

    it("swapExactOutputSingle", async function () {
        const wethAmountInMax = 10n ** 18n;
        const daiAmountOut = 100n * 10n ** 18n;

        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).deposit({ value: wethAmountInMax });
        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).approve(swapExamples.address, wethAmountInMax);

        await swapExamples.swapExactOutputSingle(daiAmountOut, wethAmountInMax);

        console.log("DAI balance", await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address));
    });
});
```

I tried the test above and was expecting this test to run as I followed a YouTube tutorial and Github code, but it has not worked. I have checked related questions on here and via google searches and have not found anything that helps with this specific issue of properties of undefined (reading 'address'). Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please add log at first line of function and make sure swapExamples deployed completely and console.log(swapExamples.address) returns correct value.

Comment: I changed the JS test code to:
```await weth.connect(accounts[0]).approve(console.log(swapExamples.address), amountIn)```
and inside SwapExamples.sol contract, I imported ```import "hardhat/console.sol";``` and on the first lines of the functions added:
```console.log("The address: ", address(this));```
I also tried msg.sender instead of address(this). It is still getting the same error. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: When I add ```console.log(swapExamples.address)``` inside the ```before(async () => { }``` portion of the code, it prints an address. However, the swapExamples.address or console.log(swapExamples.address) does not print when inside of ```it("swapExactInputSingle", async function () { }```. Any reason for this difference? Thanks

Comment: Define the variable `swapExamplesAddress`. Then, in the before section, set `swapExamplesAddress = swapExamples.address`. Replace all instances of swapExamples.address with the newly defined variable swapExamplesAddress and give it a try.